# Redux Toolkit - Actions may not have an undefined "type" property. Have you misspelled a constant?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am using the redux toolkit but I am getting "Actions may not have an undefined "type" property. Have you misspelled a constant?"

I can't notice where is my problem, can anyone help me with this?

```js
export const savePartner = createAsyncThunk('partner/savePartner', async (partnerData, { dispatch }) => {
    const response = await axios.post('admin/partners/', {
        name: partnerData.name,
        externalId: partnerData.externalId,
        eaccount: partnerData.eaccount,
        cashAccount: partnerData.cashAccount,
        externalGLAccount: partnerData.externalGLAccount,
        kosGiroId: partnerData.kosGiroId,
    });
    const data = await response.data;
    return dispatch(data);
});


const partnerSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'partner',
    initialState: null,
    reducers: {
        resetPartner: () => null,
        newPartner: {
            reducer: (state, action) => action.payload,
            prepare: event => ({
                payload: {
                    name: "",
                    externalId: "",
                    eaccount: "",
                    cashAccount: "",
                    externalGLAccount: "",
                    kosGiroId: "",
                    // status: ""
                }
            })
        }
    },
    extraReducers: {
        [getPartner.fulfilled]: (state, action) => action.payload,
        [savePartner.fulfilled]: (state, action) => action.payload,
        // [editPartner.fulfilled]: (state, action) => action.payload,
        [removePartner.fulfilled]: (state, action) => null
    }
});

export const { newPartner, resetPartner } = partnerSlice.actions;

export default partnerSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error states, when dispatching an action you should mention which action you refer to.

My guess you don't want to dispatch an action in the async thunk:

```
export const savePartner = createAsyncThunk('partner/savePartner', async (partnerData, { dispatch }) => {
    const response = await axios.post('admin/partners/', {
        name: partnerData.name,
        externalId: partnerData.externalId,
        eaccount: partnerData.eaccount,
        cashAccount: partnerData.cashAccount,
        externalGLAccount: partnerData.externalGLAccount,
        kosGiroId: partnerData.kosGiroId,
    });
    const data = await response.data;
    return data;
});
```

If you do, sometimes it done to trigger ANOTHER action after making the thunk, you need to specify to which action your refer to:

```
// GOOD
dispatch({type: 'someOtherAction', payload: data);

// BAD
dispatch(data); // Which action is it?
```